# How to solve the conflict in integrating google plus and youtube in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios6, youtube-api, google-plus

I have got a problem in integrating google plus and youtube in my iOS application.First I have integrated Google plus framework and it worked well.But When I tried to integrate Youtube files with my Xcode project compiler errors came.I think there are some conflicts between libGDataTouchStaticLib.a of Youtube and libGooglePlusUniversal.a of Google Plus.A lot of Errors are coming among them one is below.

```
uplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GTMHTTPFetcher.request_ in:
/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GoSayIt_v3- bpbdvhqiblfiafeulvjgqcnzeisq/Build/Intermediates/GoSayIt v3.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoSayIt v3.build/Objects-normal/i386/GTMHTTPFetcher.o
/Users/admin/Desktop/backup/goSayit_v.1.0.0/GoSayIt v3/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
```

If I remove libGDataTouchStaticLib.a Error occurs in Youtube section and If I remove libGooglePlusUniversal.a Error occurs in Google Plus.What Should I do If I need to Integrate both?Please Help me.Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You might have luck posting in the Objective-C Google APIs client library's mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-api-objectivec-client) or issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/list).